# Upstart: Why two processes when running as a different user?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, node.js, monit, upstart

I want to keep a nodejs app running, so I followed this: http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit and installed Monit and Upstart which have been working perfectly for a couple of months. I just added a feature to my app that allows disk writes and am getting permissions errors. I went looking for everything because it seemed the permissions errors shouldn't be the problem. It turns out that the user that I start with Upstart is not actually the user that is running the app!

When I run:

```
sudo -u deploy NODE_ENV=production node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
```

Either via Monit/Upstart, or just via SSH, it creates 2 processes. From `ps ax`:

```
2869 ?        Ss     0:00 sudo -u deploy node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
2878 ?        Sl     0:01 node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
```

When I log in as the `deploy` user and just run:

```
NODE_ENV=production node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
```

There is only 1 process!

```
3131 pts/1    Sl+    0:04 node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
```

This issue is that for some reason, the second process doesn't have the correct permissions to write and seems to be the one doing the work. Everything is perfect when I don't use Upstart including the writes, but I need Upstart/Monit to keep my nodejs app running.

What's the best way to configue Monit/Upstart in this case, then? I want to keep low permissions (hence the `deploy` user which does not have sudo) and I want the app to start when it crashes.

This is my Upstart script:

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/home/deploy"

    echo $$ > /var/run/[name of my app].pid
    exec sudo -u deploy NODE_ENV=production node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js >> /srv/www/log/[name of my app].sys.log 2>&1
end script
```

Anything wrong there?

The tutorial says to use `sudo -u user ...` in order to run it as the user you want. But that's the thing that's causing the problem.

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: have you tried the obvious : manually change your user to "deploy" and just touch a file in that folder? Are you perhaps in a chroot environment and showing us the output not from root but from deploy perspective?

Comment: @DennisNolte Good thought - I was logged in as my own user (not deploy nor root). But when I log in via deploy, the permissions on `locales` is the same (`drwxrwxr-x`) and the permissions on the enclosing folder is `drwxr-xr-x`. So don't think it helps much in this case - I can easily create and delete folders as deploy without `sudo`.

Comment: try this in test environment please:
http://www.hacksparrow.com/two-common-nodejs-npm-permission-denied-errors-on-linux.html
   curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

Comment: @DennisNolte The `deploy` user is the one that I use to install npm packages all the time. It does it fine. In fact the app has been running and working for a month, but this was the first time I've needed the app to be able to make writes. `Deploy` doesn't have sudo access to I don't think I can run that. Anyway, as I said the `deploy` user can use `mkdir` via SSH, but for some reason the app cannot do it.

Comment: The two processes is a red herring. E.g. `root            51145   0.0  0.0  2443216   1864 s007  S+    4:32PM   0:00.01 sudo -u mwagner NODE_ENV=production sleep 600` `mwagner         51137   0.0  0.0  2432764    500 s006  S+    4:30PM   0:00.00 sleep 100` Run `ps auxw | grep node` and post that output. Edit: yay horrible formatting.

Comment: @MarkWagner The relevant output from `ps ax` is in the question. When I run via Upstart or via SSH as above, it get those two processes. When I log in as `deploy` I only get one process and the site works.

Comment: I said `ps auxw` not `ps ax`.

Comment: @MarkWagner, sorry, my mistake. I didn't even know that existed. Here it is: `root      2871  0.0  0.1  53528  1940 ?        Ss   00:00   0:00 sudo -u deploy NODE_ENV=production node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
deploy    2880 15.1  5.8 1000652 58908 ?       Sl   00:00   0:01 node /srv/www/[name of my app]/dist/app.js
paul      2992  0.0  0.0   9452   948 pts/1    S+   00:00   0:00 grep --color=auto node`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo persists as long as the process is running, so the solution is to use the setuid and setgid stanzas of upstart. The problem with that is that the line that sends the PID of the daemon needs root privileges. Here is a workaround:

[name].conf:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

env HOME=/home/deploy
env NODE_ENV=production

setuid deploy
setgid deploy

exec node /srv/www/[name]/dist/app.js
```

[name]-pidfile.conf

```
start on started [name]
stop on stopped [name]

pre-start script
    initctl status name | cut -d" " -f4 > /var/run/[name].pid
end script

post-stop exec rm -f /var/run/[name].pid
```

Comment: Very interesting! I spent hours trying to get `setuid` and `setgid` working but didn't know about the second file. This gets rid of the root process and the app is only running once, under deploy. There still seems to be a difference between this and just logging in as `deploy` to run the app. Why? When Upstart starts the app, the app still doesn't have permission to write, but when I log in as `deploy` and start the app, it does. Running `ps auxw | grep node` I basically get the same output (deploy user running my app)

Comment: Well if the file already exists as the deploy user, then you can overwrite it as the same user. The problem is, /var/run is destroyed and recreated on boot, so the permissions fail.

Comment: Dang, looks like another dead end. Thanks anyway, interesting answer!

Comment: On further inspection: when I reboot, the app starts, but doesn't have permissions to write, so my app fails (500 error). When Monit sees this 2 mins later, it restarts the app via Upstart and everything works. It's hacky and means my app is down for longer than I would want, but working. I'd love to get this cleaner. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your app write its pid file itself too? Maybe change the pidfile job to `start on starting [name]` and then use `pre-start exec touch /var/run/[name].pid` instead of the script.

Comment: my app does not write that file, no. I tried this but it made no difference. Can't get my head around why, when starting an app as a user and even inspecting the process, seeing it is that user, that app then cannot do the things that the user when logged in can do. What's going on here?

Comment: sorry if this is stupid question, why u need to set `env HOME=/home/deploy`

Comment: @slier I just added it because the OP had an `export HOME=/home/deploy` and I figured his app needed it.